# How do I get this code to animate smoothly in all browsers, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a quick question...why does this code do a zig-zag animation, see code:

```
$('.photos li img').click(function(){   
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    offset.left -= 40;
    offset.top -= 57;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset.top ,
        scrollLeft: offset.left
    });
});
```

I'm working on a portfolio site and the animation only works smoothly in Firefox & Chrome...Is there another way to make it animate smoothly in all browsers?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [adjusting the frame rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940054/how-to-determine-the-best-framerate-setinterval-delay-to-use-in-a-javascript).

The animation sequence is moving the objects faster than the browser can display them. IE is quite slow.